# select all rows which satisfy constraints from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

my database (MySQL) contains 5 tables.

It should describe certain actions, states and constraints.

For any action to be executable all of its constraints must be met.
Each state assures that certain constraints are met:

1. Actions (ID, name)
2. States (ID, name)
3. Constraints (ID, name)
4. has_constraints (Action_ID, Constraint_ID)
5. assures_constraints (State_ID, Constraint_ID)

My Question is: how do I select all actions, which are executable for a given state?

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Comment: @Matthew Farwell: All sorts of things but I'm somewhat SQL-illiterate. Just experimented with some nested selects. It's not homework, btw. I just want to know

Comment: It sounds to me like you're looking for a JOIN, sl0815.  Read the MySQL docs on JOINs and then try to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: This is a relational division problem. Try searching SO for that: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+relational+division

Comment: Check this question and answers: stackoverflow.com/questions/6523856/newbie-question-n-n-join-that-matches-all-a-list/

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482803/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-nested-query-in-this-type-of-sql-select/5482912#5482912

Comment: And Celko's article **Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division**: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM actions a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (
   SELECT 1
     FROM has_constraints hc
    WHERE hc.action_id = a.id
      AND NOT EXISTS
          (    
      SELECT 1 
        FROM assure_constraints ac
       WHERE ac.state_id = $my_state_id
         AND ac.constraint_id = hc.constraint_id))
```

- Retrieves all actions with no constraints that a state wouldn't allow.
- Includes actions without constraints at all.

Comment: Nice. I prefer `SELECT *` inside `EXISTS` subqueries but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @ypercube: AFAIK `SELECT 1` is the canonical syntax. But as you said, really a matter of personal preference. Maybe stuff for one of those questions we aren't supposed to post on SO. ;)

Comment: @ypercube: Clearly, my "canonical" was unfounded. I've seen, you have seen my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710153/what-is-easier-to-read-in-exists-subqueries

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select using JOINs, I cannot tell the exact table schema fro your example.
But take a look in [MySQLs documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and learn about JOINs, they will take you where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't don't know the columns you from each of those tables but according to your statement perhaps we could also have the statement done like this:

```
SELECT 
<columns>
FROM
has_constraints `constraint` INNER JOIN actions action ON `constraint`.action_id = action.id
RIGHT JOIN assure_constraints assure ON assure.constraint_id = `constraint`.id
WHERE constraint.state_id = <id of state>
```

If you want to get some columns from the state table you may add it on the join statements just inside the from.