# SQL Server: Error 4145 while performing a multiple column search

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
delete from Copies
where (id,MovieID) IN (
select distinct id,MovieID
from copies 
where type = 'dubbed' AND (id,MovieID) NOT IN (select id,MovieID from Bookings))
```

Which I am basically trying to delete all the 'dubbed' copies in one table of mine which were never booked/reserved. When I execute the query, it is informed that:

*An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.*

I know that this query runs fine in PostgreSQL, but I am experiencing problems to execute it at SQL Server 2012. What should I do here?

Comment: Are you allowed to have multiple columns in an ``IN`` expression?

Comment: not sure, should I use exists instead?

Comment: I've never seen more than one value used on the left side of an ``IN`` clause. Rewriting it as an ``EXISTS`` should do the trick.

Comment: @acfrancis: Ad-hoc row expressions `(id, movieid)` work just fine in Postgres. [But `NOT IN` regularly surprises people when NULL values are involved in any way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694).

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: The OP says it runs fine in PostgreSQL. I don't think multiple columns are allowed in SQL Server (where the OP is having trouble) but I could be wrong.

Comment: @acfrancis: Yeah, I don't think the row expression `(id, movieid)` would work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This version should work in SQL server.

```
delete 
    c
from
    copies c
where
    type = 'dubbed' and
    not exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            Bookings b
        Where 
            c.id = b.id and
            c.movieId = b.MovieId
    )
```

Comment: what "select 'x'" should be?

Comment: anything, it doesn't matter. I use 'x'. Some people use 1 or null. You're not interested in what is returned, just whether something is returned.

Comment: The following errors are occuring: 
The multi-part identifier "c.id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "c.filmeId" could not be bound.
What it could be?

Comment: I've no idea. Using Erwin's example, here's an SQLFiddle showing this statement works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbc2c/7

Comment: @Mudkip: `filmeId`? You had `movieid` in the question. @Laurence's answer should work just fine (+1). The `DELETE c FROM copies c` part is non-standard SQL-Server syntax.

Comment: Correct, it should be MovieID! My bad

Answer (score 1):

That's how you should do it in *Postgres* to begin with:

```
DELETE FROM copies
WHERE  type = 'dubbed'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1           -- it's irrelevant what goes here
   FROM   bookings b
   WHERE  b.id = copies.id
   AND    b.movieid = copies.movieid
   );
```

The same works in SQL-Server (2008 or later at least) as well.

[**->SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbc2c/2)

[More about the comment in above code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710153/what-is-easier-to-read-in-exists-subqueries)