# Variables for identifiers inside IF EXISTS in a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, exists

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_now()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    row     record;
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'in';
    FOR row IN 
        select relname from pg_stat_user_tables
        WHERE schemaname='public' AND relname LIKE '%test%'
    LOOP    
    IF EXISTS(SELECT row.relname.tm FROM row.relname
              WHERE row.relname.tm < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '90 minutes'
              LIMIT 1)              
    THEN
    -- EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || quote_ident(row.relname);
    RAISE INFO 'Dropped table: %', quote_ident(row.relname);

    END IF;

    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Could you tell me how to use variables in `SELECT` which is inside `IF EXISTS`? At the present moment, `row.relname.tm` and `row.relname` are treated literally which is not I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_now()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl   regclass;
   _found int;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN 
      SELECT relid
      FROM   pg_stat_user_tables
      WHERE  schemaname = 'public'
      AND    relname LIKE '%test%'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format($f$SELECT 1 FROM %s
                        WHERE  tm < now() - interval '90 min'$f$, _tbl);
      GET DIAGNOSTICS _found = ROW_COUNT;
      IF _found > 0 THEN
         -- EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || _tbl;
         RAISE NOTICE 'Dropped table: %', _tbl;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- `row` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in the SQL standard. It's use is allowed in Postgres, but it's still unwise. I make it a habbit to prepend psql variable with an underscore `_` to avoid any naming conflicts.
- You don't don't select the whole *row* anyway, just the table name in this example. Best use a variable of type `regclass`, thereby avoiding SQL injection by way of illegal table names automatically. Details in this related answer:
  [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- You don't need `LIMIT` in an `EXISTS` expression, which only checks for the existence of *any* rows. And you don't need meaningful target columns for the same reason. Just write [`SELECT 1` or `SELECT *` or something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710153/what-is-easier-to-read-in-exists-subqueries).
- You need **dynamic SQL** for queries with variable identifiers. Plain SQL does not allow for that. I.e.: build a query string and `EXECUTE` it. Details in this closely related answer:
  [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)
- The same is true for a `DROP` statement, should you want to run it. I added a comment.

Comment: One question: what does `$f$` do in `format`? Can't find in the docs.

Comment: @Tom: That's nested [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build your query as a string then execute that - see the section on executing dynamic commands in the plpgsql section [of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html).