# Check for integer in string array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, types, string-formatting, plpgsql

I am trying to check a string array for existence of a converted integer number. This sits inside of a procedure where:

`nc_ecosite` is an `integer` variable
`current_consite` is a string array
`ecosite` is an `integer`
`current_ecosite_nc` is `double`

```
IF to_char(nc_ecosite, '999') IN
   (select current_consite from current_site_record
    where current_ecosite_nc::integer = nc_ecosite) THEN
       ecosite := nc_ecosite;
```

The result always comes from the `ELSIF` that follows the first `IF`. This occurs when `nc_ecosite` is in the array (from checks). Why is `ecosite` not being populated with `nc_ecosite` when values are matching?

I am working with Postgres 9.3 inside pgAdmin.

Comment: Any chance you can post more of the function, along with inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs?  I sort of follow you, but some concrete examples would help to see what you want vs what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following to provide the desired result:

```
IF nc_ecosite in 
(select (unnest(string_to_array(current_consite, ',')))::integer 
from current_site_record 
where current_ecosite_nc::integer = nc_ecosite) THEN
   ecosite := nc_ecosite::integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate reason for the problem is that `to_char()` inserts a leading blank for your given pattern (legacy reasons - to make space for a potential negative sign). Use the [**`FM`** Template Pattern Modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) to avoid that:

```
to_char(nc_ecosite, 'FM999')
```

Of course, it would be best to operate with matching data types to begin with - if at all possible.

Barring that, I suggest this faster and cleaner statement:

```
   SELECT INTO ecosite  nc_ecosite  -- variable or column??
   WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM current_site_record c
      WHERE  current_ecosite_nc::integer = nc_ecosite
      AND    to_char(nc_ecosite, 'FM999') = ANY(current_consite)
      );

   IF NOT FOUND THEN  ... -- to replace your ELSIF
```

Make sure you don't run into naming conflicts between parameters, variables and column names! A widespread convention is to prepend variable names with `_` (and never use the same for column names). But you better table-qualify column names in all queries anyway. You did not make clear which is a column and which is a variable ...

I might be able to optimize the statement further if I had the complete function and table definition.

Related:

- [Remove blank-padding from to_char() output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242202/remove-blank-padding-from-to-char-output/22242593#22242593)
- [Variables for identifiers inside IF EXISTS in a plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193432/variables-for-identifiers-inside-if-exists-in-a-plpgsql-function/20203005#20203005)
- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105902/3684)