# "missing FROM-clause entry" in PLPGSQL function to update a table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

I am trying to update a table in Postgres, but I get below error.
`Userid` is the primary key.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_user(username character varying, 
                                                userid character varying, 
                                                roleid integer,
                                                deptid integer, 
                                                status integer)
RETURNS integer AS 
$$
BEGIN

UPDATE public."M_User" SET public."M_User".user_name = public.update_user.username, 
    public."M_User".user_role_id = public.update_user.roleid, 
    public."M_User".dept_id = public.update_user.deptid, 
    public."M_User".status = public.update_user.status 
    WHERE public."M_User".user_id = userid;
    
RETURN 0;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.update_user ('ji','gis', 123, 24, 1);
```

Error:

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "update_user"
> LINE 1: ...E public."M_User" SET public."M_User".user_name = public.upd...
>                                                              ^
> QUERY:  UPDATE public."M_User" SET public."M_User".user_name = public.update_user.username, 
>   public."M_User".user_role_id = public.update_user.roleid, 
>   public."M_User".dept_id = public.update_user.deptid, 
>   public."M_User".status = public.update_user.status 
>   WHERE public."M_User".user_id = userid
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_user(character varying,character varying,integer,integer,integer) line 4 at SQL
> ```
>
> statement
> SQL state: 42P01

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_user(_username varchar, 
                                                _userid varchar, 
                                                _roleid integer,
                                                _deptid integer, 
                                                _status integer)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE sql AS 
$func$
UPDATE public."M_User" u
SET    user_name    = _username
     , user_role_id = _roleid
     , dept_id      = _deptid
     , status       = _status 
WHERE  u.user_id = _userid
AND   (u.user_name, u.user_role_id, u.dept_id, u.status) IS DISTINCT FROM
      ( _username ,       _roleid ,  _deptid ,  _status)  -- optional addition
RETURNING u.user_id;
$func$
```

You *can* qualify function parameters with the function name to disambiguate, but that's typically an awkward solution. Breaks when renaming the function. There are other ways. See:

- [PL/pgSQL column name the same as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600500/pl-pgsql-column-name-the-same-as-variable/29604751#29604751)

I like to prefix parameters and variables with an underscore, and never do the same for column names. Not standard, but a widespread convention. Make it a habit to table-qualify all column names, and you are safe. A table alias helps to keep the noise down. Basics in [the manual on `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

But target columns in an `UPDATE` statement cannot be qualified. (They are never ambiguous.)

I added an optional predicate to skip the UPDATE if it wouldn't change anything. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

You do not need PL/pgSQL for this. (Though you *can*, of course.) A simpler SQL function does the job. See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

`RETURN 0` does nothing useful. I changed it to return the effective `user_id` of the updated row. (Typically the same as the input `_userid`, but it might differ with triggers.) The important difference: you only get the return value if a row is actually updated, making it useful. Else, you might as well declare the function as `RETURNS void`. Just as useful as an unconditional `RETURN 0;`, but cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) says one can refer to an input as `function_name.parameter_name`, so try removing references to the `schema_name`

```
UPDATE public."M_User" 
SET user_name = update_user.username, 
    user_role_id = update_user.roleid, 
    dept_id = update_user.deptid, 
    status = update_user.status 
WHERE user_id = update_user.userid;
```

Comment: Also the `SET column_name = column_val` has to be just the column name not table_name.column_name per [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-update.html) '...Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column ...'. So, `user_name = update_user.username`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes of course, thanks for seeing it!