# Return value for ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, return-value, plpgsql, upsert

As instructed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600500/pl-pgsql-column-name-the-same-as-variable/29604751?noredirect=1#comment124384996_29604751) comment.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_upsert(
        _parent_id int, 
        _some_text text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   a text;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO parent_tree (parent_id, some_text)
   VALUES (_parent_id,_some_text)
   ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING
   RETURNING 'ok' into a;
   return a;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN return 'JUZ ISTNIEJE';
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

1. Not sure what this means:

   `IF NOT FOUND THEN return 'JUZ ISTNIEJE';`
2. If no conflict then return `ok`, which makes sense. But when conflict it will yield null. Is it possible to BOTH have `on conflict do nothing` also return `not ok` or when conflict happens, just `raise notice parent_id should be unique`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated [my referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604751/939860) now to fix an error, which seems to have been the main cause for the confusion.

> 1. NOT Sure what does `IF NOT FOUND THEN return 'JUZ ISTNIEJE';` mean?

"JUZ ISTNIEJE" is Polish for "already exists" - that's what the OP wants to return over there. The sole point is to return a meaningful text instead of nothing (`NULL`) - which seems to address your next question:

> 2. If no conflict then return `ok`, which makes sense. But when conflict it will yields null. Is it possible to BOTH have `on conflict do nothing` and also return `not ok` or when conflict happens, just `raise notice parent_id should be unique`.

Yes, and that's what my answer over there does, now that it's fixed. Your function becomes:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_upsert(_parent_id int, _some_text text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO parent_tree (parent_id, some_text)
   VALUES (_parent_id,_some_text)
   ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
   
   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN 'ok';
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'parent_id already exists: %', _parent_id;  -- optional!
      RETURN 'not ok';  -- or whatever
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```