# Find IDs with only one observation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    the_visitor_id varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    the_visitor_visit timestamp NOT NULL,
    the_visitor_returning text
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('VIS01', '2019-05-02 09:00:00','YES' ), 
       ('VIS01', '2019-05-04 12:00:00',NULL ), 
       ('VIS01', '2019-05-05 18:00:00',NULL ), 
       ('VIS02', '2019-05-06 18:30:00',NULL), 
       ('VIS02', '2019-05-15 12:00:00',NULL), 
       ('VIS03', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','YES'),
       ('VIS04', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','NULL');
```

And I would like to filter out all visitor_id's that have only one observation (or record). In this case VIS03 and VIS04, so I must end up with VIS01 and VIS02. I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(the_visitor_id) the_visitor_id, 
the_visitor_visit, the_visitor_returning 
FROM my_table
```

The expected result should be:

```
the_visitor_id   the_visitor_visit    the_visitor_returning
VIS01            2019-05-02 09:00:00  YES
VIS01            2019-05-04 12:00:00    
VIS01            2019-05-05 18:00:00    
VIS02            2019-05-06 18:30:00    
VIS02            2019-05-15 12:00:00
```

But I guess that something like a rank is needed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably other ways of doing this, but it you create a derived table CTE of only the visitor_ids that have more than 1 row, then use that in the join to your table. Obviously, if my_table is large an index would enhance the performance.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT the_visitor_id
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY the_visitor_id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
SELECT my_table.*
FROM my_table
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.the_visitor_id = my_table.the_visitor_id
```

Comment: hello @Ed Mendez, thank you. It works fine, but if only with one column in the CTE. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` can use an index:

```sql
SELECT the_visitor_id, the_visitor_visit, the_visitor_returning 
FROM   my_table t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM my_table
   WHERE  the_visitor_id = t1.the_visitor_id
   AND    ctid <> t1.ctid
   );
```

Using `ctid` because you didn't disclose the PK or any UNIQUE column of the table. About `ctid`:

- [Postgresql group by for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659545/postgresql-group-by-for-multiple-lines/52670170#52670170)

Ideally, you would have a `UNIQUE` index on `(the_visitor_id, any_notnull_column)` and use that column in the query. Substantially faster than a full sequential scan, count, join (another seq or idx scan).

Barring any usable index, using a **window function** allows us to at least keep it to a single sequential scan:

```sql
SELECT the_visitor_id, the_visitor_visit, the_visitor_returning 
FROM  (
    SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY the_visitor_id) AS ct
    FROM   my_table
    ) sub
WHERE  ct > 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1a5e1cc60561d5f8bb9c3362258bdcc3)*