# How can I use WITH together with IF in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, exists

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS boolean security definer AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

with zzz as (select foo from data)

 IF EXISTS (select 1 from zzz) THEN
 
  return true;
  
  ELSE
     return false;
  END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
> LINE 10:  IF EXISTS (select 1 from zzz) THEN
> ```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You are mixing `SQL` (`WITH`) with `plpgsql`(`IF`). Lose the `WITH` statement and  use  `PERFORM foo from data` and then `IF FOUND ...` per [Perform](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I used:

```
$BODY$

BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS

SELECT foo from data;

 IF EXISTS (select 1 from mytable) THEN
 
  return true;
  
  ELSE
     return false;
  END IF;


END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: Why the temp table? That does not make sense. Bohemian's answer is way more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Simplify to a single return statement:

```
return exists(select foo from data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Bohemian provided, you can radically simplify to:

```
RETURN EXISTS(SELECT foo FROM data);
```

However, that would suggest that `foo` matters, which it does not (if the column exists, else an exception is raised). [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) returns `true` if at least one row is returned, no matter the content: can even be all NULL values for that purpose. Else it returns `false`. Never `null`. Less misleading:

```
RETURN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM data);
RETURN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data);
```

Postgres also accepts an empty `SELECT` list (my preference):

```
RETURN EXISTS(SELECT FROM data);
```

See:

- [What is easier to read in EXISTS subqueries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710153/what-is-easier-to-read-in-exists-subqueries)

Or use the syntax shorthand `TABLE` for the simple case:

```
RETURN EXISTS(TABLE data);
```

See:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

PL/pgSQL would be overkill for the simple case, a plain SQL function or just the bare statement would do:

```
SELECT EXISTS(TABLE data);
```

To integrate the logic in a more complex PL/pgSQL function, the special variable `FOUND` (like [Adrian commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637712/postgres-how-can-i-use-with-together-with-if-in-function#comment116050844_65637712)) is often instrumental. Or `GET DIAGNOSTICS ...` for dynamic SQL.

See:

- [Dynamic SQL (EXECUTE) as condition for IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449011/dynamic-sql-execute-as-condition-for-if-statement/8449341#8449341)